# How to constrain NSWindow's contentView to not exceed screen size?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, autolayout

I'm trying to constrain a `NSWindow.contentView` to never be larger than the screen size (i.e. the maximum `NSWindow` size).
Here's the (simplified) view hierarchy:

```
NSWindow
    NSThemeFrame
        NSWindow.contentView
            Header [height: 200]
            GrowableSubview [height: flexible]
```

The height priority of `GrowableSubview` is `NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow`, such that it can grow the window when the height of that view changes (due to some user interaction).

The problem starts when `Header.height + GrowableSubview.height` exceeds the screen height.
Since the window cannot grow larger than the screen size, the `contentView` will get clipped.

Currently the `Header` view gets clipped on the top (left side of image), instead of the `GrowableSubview` getting clipped on the bottom (right side of image).

[image]

How can I make sure the window `contentView` is positioned statically at the top, or prevent `GrowableSubview` to be larger than the screen height?